# AngularJS: Can't load angular.min.js file

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a project using AngularJS. My html file looks like:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
  ....
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load the html file I get an error in the console:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   and the console points to the line that imports the angular.min.js file.

My app.js file is:

```
var app = angular.module("flexbox", []);

app.controller("aside-buttons-ctrl", [$scope, function($scope) {
  $scope.buttons = ['Home', 'Workflow', 'Statistics', 'Calendar', 'Users', 'Settings'];
}]);
```

I checked the link and it works. What can be the problem?

Comment: Check your app.js path. also share your app.js code.

Comment: @MichalPaszkiewicz,  when I say "line that imports the angular.min.js..." I mean that the error points to line 5 in index.html file, which is the line number of: "<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com...."

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/pen/ObqqNX

Comment: Same error if you try in incognito mode in Chrome?

Comment: @tasseKATT yes.

Comment: And if you use this: `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"`

Comment: @tasselKATT In his codepen Angular is correctly imported, the problem is different.

Comment: If you try without `app.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a synthax error in the declaration of your controller. Injected dependencies should be write in quotes (*eg: `'$scope'`*).

Change this line:

```
app.controller("AsideButtonsCtrl", [$scope, function($scope) {
```

To:

```
app.controller("AsideButtonsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

---

[**Forked you CodePen here.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBMMJX)

Comment: thanks. But I still get the error: "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". what does this mean?

Comment: I don't know... As you can see it works on [your CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBMMJX). The problem seems to come from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting error while loading `css/styles.css` and `app.js`.
Make sure `app.js` present in the same directory where `index.html` is located.
And as well as '`css/styles`'

You will get this error when the browser fails to load a file. something like below.
[image]

There is no issue with this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
app.controller("AsideButtonsCtrl", [$scope, function($scope) {
```

To:

```
app.controller("AsideButtonsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

**try this**

```
   angular.module("flexbox", [])
      .controller("aside-buttons-ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
          $scope.buttons = ['Home', 'Workflow', 'Statistics', 'Calendar', 'Users', 'Settings'];
      }]);
```

You also can use like this.

```
       angular.module("flexbox", [])
      .controller("aside-buttons-ctrl", function($scope){
          $scope.buttons = ['Home', 'Workflow', 'Statistics', 'Calendar', 'Users', 'Settings'];
      });
```